# Add distinct items to an array in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add to an array distinct item but this error appears "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" any help

```
function unique(list) {
  var result = [];
  $.each(list, function(i, e) {
    if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Did you include the librairies that you use ?

Comment: yes, everything is added

Comment: Use angular.forEach instead of $. Otherwise include jQuery libray.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you didn't load jQuery.
Btw to implement this function you don't need that.

Try this:

```
function unique(list) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (result.indexOf(list[i]) == -1) {
            result.push(list[i]);
        }
    };

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did load JQuery in your, have you defined it as $?

You can use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)  and

[Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to solve your problem.

SO does not allow me for more that two links.
but you can use the ES6 array.find function to do the same job